# puppet installing pip rather than pip3 packages using the pip3 provider only on the first run

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, puppet

Given that pyton3 and pip3 are installed in the machine already I'm declaring the boto3 package as follows:

```
  package { 'boto3':
    ensure => present,
    provider => 'pip3',
  }
```

The issue is that when you run puppet for the first time you get:

```
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 freeze'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:22:58.058603923+
00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 --version'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:22:58.7344189
24+00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 freeze'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:22:59.317146692+
00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 --version'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:22:59.9823109
65+00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing: '/bin/pip install -q boto3'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:23:00.569312158+00:00"}
```

and when you run it the second time it works as expected:

```
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 freeze'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:39:50.080139315+
00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 --version'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:39:50.7515434
28+00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 freeze'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:39:51.332423254+
00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing '/bin/pip3 --version'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:39:51.9972545
96+00:00"}
{"level":"debug","message":"Executing: '/bin/pip3 install -q boto3'","source":"Puppet","tags":["debug"],"file":null,"line":null,"version":1,"@timestamp":"2017-06-08T14:39:52.586167287+00:00"}
```

The above happens without making any change at all in the environment between puppet runs.

culprit has to be in 
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/4.10.1/lib/puppet/provider/package/pip3.rb
 ￼
which basically imports https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/4.10.1/lib/puppet/provider/package/pip.rb

I'd like to file a bug but I can't figure out what is going on
I'm pre backing boto3 on the image that I'm using to spin up the servers.
I'm using Puppet 4.10.1 and I'm running `puppet apply` locally (masterless) in the servers.

Comment: Following the stack trace within the code, I would blame this: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/4.10.1/lib/puppet/provider/package/pip.rb#L129. It should probably be `pip_cmd`. You certainly have enough to file an issue on the JIRA at this point though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll file a bug then, I also found weird that `lazy_pip` definition

Comment: I created a ticket in jira, let's see how it goes
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/CPR-426